# Next js frontend only app (static + everything on client side)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I want to use next js instead of react but for similar type of build

Static client side spa
No server should be required
No pre rendering
Complete app on client side

I need guidance to do setup this.
How to do this setup? What configurations do I need to do?

Comment: Nextjs is build on top of React, so you won't use Nextjs without React. A (web)server is still needed to deliver the spa, even if there is only static data and no server-side rendering. Why do you want to use Nextjs if you don't want to use server-side rendering? Afaik the server-side functionalities are the whole point of Nextjs.

Comment: What you are looking for is "React without Next.js" not the opposite

Comment: I understand what you guys are saying. But Next has better file based router, and many other better features.

Comment: I have used Nuxt3 and I could do it there. Server false and CSR true and then static generate. Isn't there any way to do it in Next?

Comment: Please take a look at Next.js static exports - https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/deploying/static-exports if that's what you need. However, if your goal is to build 100% client-side SPA, then you probably don't need Next.js at all. You can take a look at Vite - https://vitejs.dev

Comment: If you're using v13 or higher, you can add "use client" to the layout.tsx file that should make the whole app client side.

Comment: Thanks @IgorDanchenko
I tried Next for the first time. I thought it'll have 100% SPA feature like Nuxt3. Anyways, I'll just use vite + react. thank you